# Why does this SMD LED only work on AC?

Tags: led

I have basic electronics knowledge and have repaired many things, but I'm a little confused about this. I have a 220 V LED PCB like this:

[image: Seller's image of PCB]

One of the LEDs is burning out and causing the whole array to flicker and die. I assumed like most things, I could replace the LED after finding out what voltage and current it was. When I desoldered and tried to power up one of the good SMD LEDs on a DC supply, I could not get it to light up, even after supplying between 3-28 V (the maximum my supply can provide). However, when I hooked it up to a variable AC transformer, I got the LED to light up fine at around 22 V.

Now I'm confused. Is this an AC-only LED? I've never heard of that.

Comment: It would be a good idea to link to the product page - or, even better, to the datasheet.

Comment: 22 Vac peak rectified is ~31 Vdc. But sure, 28 Vdc should be close enough unless you have 29 V Vf to overcome. How did you connect it?

Comment: Was your DC power backwards?

Comment: Some low power off-line power supplies use a capacitor to provide part of the voltage drop. These won't work so well off DC.

Comment: I removed one of the good LED's completely from the PCB and soldered two wires onto it. Then i connected it to my DC power supply. I turned the voltage up slowly from 3v all to way to max and it would not illuminate. When i connected the same bare LED to an AC transformer, it lit up when the voltage reached approx 22v.

Comment: Did you try reversing the DC polarity?

Answer (score 2):

There are some LEDs in that size package (2835) that work at 18V, such as the [Cree J-series](https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/data-sheet-JSeries-2835.pdf). I assume (and I could be wrong) that they are effectively a number of junctions in series on a single die, since the die count is specified as "one" on other manufacturer's datasheets.

Perhaps there is a higher voltage version this manufacturer is using to make 230VAC lights simpler, like 36V, or (more likely, I think) they are using two 18V dies in the one package.

At the peak of 22VAC RMS (~31V) a 36V LED would certainly be emitting a fair bit of light, though not nearly at full brightness.

Good question, that's an interesting evolution in LEDs.

Edit: [Here](https://www.bridgelux.com/sites/default/files/resource_media/DS252%20SMD%202835%201W%2036V%20Data%20sheet%20Rev%20A%2020190725.PDF) is a real-life example of a two-die 36V white LED that may be the exact one used in your lamp:

[image]

Comment: If it helps, when the LED's were in situ on the PCB I measured the voltage drop across one and it was about 20v with a multimeter. Actually 20v in both AC and DC modes. For now i've replaced all the LED's with 3v white ones. The controller on this PCB is set with a resistor to provide a very low constant current and it's been working fine for a few hours, but i'm still very interested in working out what the original LED's were.

Comment: There's no filter capacitance so the LEDs are not seeing the 36V operating voltage all the time. Average may well be 20V. Verified by the fact you're reading AC voltage across them!

Comment: So are you saying that the chances are these LED's are 36v DC units and my DC power supply just wouldn't go high enough to illuminate them?

Comment: Yes, exactly, if you added a 9V battery in series (additive) it should work.